# Eigen decomposition of Householder operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

You probably know both "Householder" and "Eigendecomposition", but do you really know how it works geometrically?
I got stuck in  question asks me to provide the eigen decomposition of householder operator H=I-2ww* where ‖w‖=1, geometrically!
I know that the eigen-values are [-1, 1 ...1] but I cannot understand about the eigen-vectors and in particular I cannot depict the solution, geometrically!

Can anybody possibly help me to understand it through drawing a geometrical interpretation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that if $v$ is orthogonal to $w$, then $H \cdot v = v$. So geometrically, a whole hyperplane is left invariant.
Now, also remark that $H \cdot w = -w $. In other words, $w$ gets reflected.

Putting those two together, $H$ is the orthogonal symmetry with respect to the hyperplane orthogonal to $w$.

And indeed, $H$ is an orthogonal symmetry (i.e. $H$ is self adjoint and $H^2 = I$).

Comment: I think I get what you say. But,  how are the eigen-vectors depicted here?
If I want to draw a geometrical illustration, assuming hyper-plane H goes through the origin, what are eigen-vectors? Could you possibly show me a geometrical illustration please?

Comment: Well, $w$ is clearly an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $-1$, and any $v$ orthogonal to $v$ is also an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $1$.
A full orthogonal eigenbasis is given by any ortonomal basis of the hyperplane orthogonal to $w$, and $w$ itself.

Comment: Now I got what you say. It makes sense. I appreciate your help